# tf.gather_nd to torch operators

Tags: tensorflow, torch, tensorrt

I saw the topics about the same problem, but my requirments are different here.
I have this line:

```
offsets = tf.gather_nd(offsets, kpt_inds, batch_dims=1)
```

While offsets is a torch tensor of `(1,1,320,256,2)` sizes, and `kpt_inds` is a tensor of `(1,k,2)` and `k` is a variable.

I want to change that operation with a set of torch operators that will produce the same output.
The operation have to choose the offsets in the specific `k` indices (that specified in `kpt_inds`).

I have already tried:

```
offsets = offsets[:, :, keypoints[:, :, 0], keypoints[:, :, 1], :]
```

It works fine, but I have a problem with it, and I must change the whole operation solely using torch operators (without python shortcuts). The reason is the underministic behaviour of tensorrt when I use this shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `.index_select` method:

```py
from einops import rearrange  # or use torch.unsqueeze instead
kpt_x = torch.ByteTensor(rearrange(keypoints[:, :, 0], '... -> 1 ...'))
kpt_y = torch.ByteTensor(rearrange(keypoints[:, :, 1], '... -> 1 1 ...'))
offsets = offsets.index_select(kpt_x)
offsets = offsets.index_select(kpt_y)
```